# Is there a way to open/redirect to a website from the controller of the .net API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-apicontroller

I simply want to launch www.facebook.com or www.youtube.com or localhost:1234 or any other url directly from the controller of my .net api.

```
objResult = bl.GetUserFromAccessTokenAsync(email);
            if (objResult != null)
            {

                objResult.PASSWORD = null;
                objResult.Token = GenerateJSONWebToken(objResult);



         *I want to redirect to the website here*


                    //}
                }
         *I want to redirect to the website here*

            }
```

Is there a way to do so? I've tried `Redirect("")`, `response.Redirect("")`

Comment: Apis are used server side. They can not redirect the browser. You need to return url as response and let the client redirect.

Comment: Sure, just return 302 code to the client with the redirect url. It'll redirect API call to whatever you want to. In case a user had called your API by typing a url in browser, it'll work perfectly.